# Callback is not working when button tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callback, mvp

I want to trigger an action on button tap with my callback. Also I have `presenter` and `coordinator`. But nothing happenes. My code is not working in this closure:

```
startViewController.output = { [weak self] action in
            switch action {
            case .registrationButtonTapped:
                self?.showRegistrationViewController()
            case .loginButtonTapped:
                self?.showLoginViewController()
            }
        }
```

In my ViewController I have `enum`:

```
    enum StartViewControllerButton {
     case registrationButtonTapped
     case loginButtonTapped 
}
```

`callback`:

```
var output: ((StartViewControllerButton) -> Void)?
```

and `selectors`:

```
@objc func registrationButtonPressed() {
        startModulPresenter.openNextScreen()
        self.output?(.registrationButtonTapped)
    }

    @objc func loginButtonPressed() {
        startModulPresenter.openNextScreen()
        self.output?(.loginButtonTapped)
    }
```

My Presenter

```
class StartModulPresenter: StartModulPresenterProtocol {
    
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    var coordinator: CoordinatorProtocol?
    
    //Init
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        
        coordinator = AuthorizationCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
    }
    
    //Functions
    
    func openNextScreen() {
        coordinator?.start()
    }
    
}
```

My Coordinator:

```
class AuthorizationCoordinator: RegistrationCoordinatorProtocol {
    
    var presenter: PresenterProtocol?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    var childCoordinators: [CoordinatorProtocol] = []
    
    //Init
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }
    
    func start() {
        presenter = StartModulPresenter(navigationController: navigationController)
        
        let startViewController = StartViewController(startModulPresenter: presenter as! StartModulPresenter)
        
        startViewController.output = { [weak self] action in
            switch action {
            case .registrationButtonTapped:
                self?.showRegistrationViewController()
            case .loginButtonTapped:
                self?.showLoginViewController()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func showRegistrationViewController() {
        let registrationViewController = RegistrationViewController()
        registrationViewController.view.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(registrationViewController, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func showLoginViewController() {
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
        loginViewController.view.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: And when are called `registrationButtonPressed()`? Is it really called? When this happens, is `self.output` non nil? The thing, is that `startViewController` is a localViewController, so it might be releaseed too soon.

Comment: @Larme, thank you for the answer! Yes, self.output is nil. What I need to do to make the callback works?

Comment: Maybe make `let startViewController` a property of `AuthorizationCoordinator`? Or it depends what's the life cycle of `AuthorizationCoordinator`. If it's released too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if `startViewController` is pushed/presented or not?

```
    func start() {
        presenter = StartModulPresenter(navigationController: navigationController)
        
        let startViewController = StartViewController(startModulPresenter: presenter as! StartModulPresenter)
        
        startViewController.output = { [weak self] action in
            switch action {
            case .registrationButtonTapped:
                self?.showRegistrationViewController()
            case .loginButtonTapped:
                self?.showLoginViewController()
            }
        }
    }
```

And, is `self.output` is nil or not? If it is nil please check your assignment call, it needed to be called before you use this variable.

```
    @objc func loginButtonPressed() {
        startModulPresenter.openNextScreen()
        self.output?(.loginButtonTapped)
    }
```

Honestly, I don't recommend you to use this design pattern, just a simple thing but the real result is too complicated.
Just use protocol-based MVC. View communicate with Controller via protocol/closure or Reactive-based with Combine (PassthroughSubject/CurrentValueSubject)